# Python - Not able to access company share point directory which uses single sign on for authentication

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, python

My company share point uses windows authentication and uses HTTPS

### I am trying to access company share point via the following code

import requests from requests_kerberos

import HTTPKerberosAuth, OPTIONAL

url_login = "https://www.company.com"

kerberos_auth = HTTPKerberosAuth(mutual_authentication=OPTIONAL)

r = requests.get(url_login, auth=kerberos_auth)

### print(r.status_code)

I am getting an error 403 b'403 FORBIDDEN'

I am having access to this path as I am able to visit this site using my windows authentication but when i am trying to do the same via python script I get the above error. Can someone help.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: not yet.......................